# Run a program when new line appears in dmesg

Tags: linux, xargs, dmesg

```
sudo dmesg -w|grep "Manufacturer: Keychron K1"| xargs -I{} xset r rate 250 70
```

It does not work, why?

I am trying to reset keyboard settings when the keyboard is reconnected, but I cannot get `dmesg -w|xargs...` combination to work. It supposed to be working, for example if I do this:

```
while :; do echo tick; sleep 1s; done|xargs -I{} date
```

I will get a new time printed every second. The idea was to use `dmesg -w` then `grep` then `xargs` but it does not work until `xargs` is killed from another terminal.

Why and how to fix?

Comment: Ok I used `ag` instead of `grep` and it worked! Must be grep bufferring issue, maybe it even is controllable by an option.

Comment: That's neither the problem you have to solve, nor a solution for what you actually need to do. Please don't implement a ["spacebar heater" / XKCD 1172](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Comment: but... why not configure your desktop manager or X-server settings to do configure your keyboard?...

Answer (score 0):

You're asking an XY(Z) problem here, see "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)".

Your problem ***X*** is "how do I automatically have input devices configured in Xorg when hotplugged?"

And for that you simply want to write a `xorg.conf.d` *InputClass* rule that will make the appropriate settings for your keyboard:

https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading9

---

However you misidentified this problem as problem ***Y*** "how to automatically execute a program upon hotplug?" – for that we have UDev

For that problem look at UDev rules: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udev

---

However misidentified problem Y as the "problem" Z "how can I execute the last part of a chain if pipe redirections, when a certain string appears". Tackling that does not solve your actual problem.

This

```
sudo dmesg -w | grep … | xargs …
```

pipes three programs together, which are all executing at the same time. `xargs` waits for the end of input and then executes whatever was passed to it as parameters. Of course `dmesg -w` will never produce an end-of-file.

Answer (score 0):

> Why

Buffering.

> how to fix?

Set line buffering of tools with `stdbuf` or `grep --line-buffered`.